# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'lookup'

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de sumar un conjunto de valores pertenecientes al *`id_jovenclub`*

```
def detalle_jc(request, id_jovenclub ):
    jc = jovenclub.objects.get(pk=id_jovenclub)
    datos=ingresos.objects.all()
    print jc.ingresos_set.all()
    **ing = ingresos.objects.aggregate(pk=id_jovenclub)**
    natural=ing.natural
    sum=0
    for ingreso in jc.ingresos_set.all():
        sum=ingreso.get_importe()

    sum=(round((sum/jc.plan_gral)*100,2))
```

Cuando ejecuto el código me da el siguiente error:

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'lookup'

Pienso debe ser porque `aggregate` no funciona con consultas pk, pero probe con `ing = ingresos.objects.annotate` y tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones de agregado de dominio, llamadas **Aggregate** en Django, realizan *operaciones matemáticas* en un *campo específico* de una tabla. Estas operaciones pueden ser<sup><sup>**1**</sup></sup>: contar, promedio, suma, máximo, mínimo... pero ojo: operaciones matemáticas sobre un campo.

En tu vista usas el método `aggregate` sobre el `id`, que generalmente es un campo numérico incremental, **pero no indicas la operación a realizar**.

Lo idel sería que usaras un campo que de mas información que el `id` para que el resultado aporte valor o te permita tomar mejores decisiones.

Este es un ejemplo de las opéraciones que puedes realizar.

#### Promedio de los ingregos

```
from django.db.models import Avg
jovenclub.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('ingresos'))
```

#### Ingresos máximos

```
from django.db.models import Max
jovenclub.objects.all().aggregate(Max('ingresos'))
```

Puedes consultar la documentación completa de **Aggregate** en [este enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/).

<sup>**1**</sup>: Sin que esto sea una lista exhaustiva.

Comment: necesito calcular los ingresos maximos pero por id de cada jovenclub

Comment: @RolyMirandaDíaz en la documentación hay un ejemplo.

Comment: eso ya lo tengo hecho aca `plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))` y funciona para calcular el plan general, o sea suma TODOS los ingresos de TODOS los joven club, pero yo deseo ver la suma de los Ingresos de cada jovenclub por separado

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta y que especifiques con claridad cuál es tu resultado esperado. Te recomiendo que sigas esta guía [mcve] y que incluyas el modelo involucrado.

Comment: mira la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64578/multiples-estadisticas-en-django