# multiples estadisticas en django

Tags: python, django

Tengo que calcular una serie de datos para mi proyecto, funciona al 100% cuando se trata de cálculo general, pero cuando trato de llevar esos mismos cálculos a las instalaciones (`jovenclubs`) por separado me devuelve una lista con todos los valores que contiene:

ejemplo: `joven club` x tiene un campo llamado `Natural`, con una serie de datos, los cuales quiero sumar.

Esta es la vista de los **valores generales**, funciona bien:

```
def inicio(request):
    plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))
    juridic_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
    natural_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
    general = juridic_gral['sum']+natural_gral['sum']
    diferencia = plan_gral['sum']-general
    porciento_general = general*100/plan_gral['sum']

    ingreso = ingresos.objects.all()

    mes = datetime.now().month
    meses=ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__month = mes)
    year = datetime.now().year
    amo=ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__year = year)
```

y esta es la vista de las **instalaciones**:

```
def detalle_jc(request, id_jovenclub ):
    jc = jovenclub.objects.get(pk=id_jovenclub)
    datos=ingresos.objects.all()
    print jc.ingresos_set.all()
    sum=0
    for ingreso in jc.ingresos_set.all():
        sum=ingreso.get_importe()
    sum=(round((sum/jc.plan_gral)*100,2))
```

Esta es la llamada en el **template**:

```
{% for ingreso in jc.ingresos_set.all %}
{{ ingreso.natural }}
{% endfor %}
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

> **3974,0 5200,0 4875,0**

Esos son los datos de el campo `Natural`, los cuales deberia sumar

**model.py:**

```
class jovenclub(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=JOVENCLUB)
    especialista = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    plan_gral = models.FloatField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre

class ingresos(models.Model):
    # mes = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    jovenclub = models.ForeignKey(jovenclub)
    natural = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    juridico = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    def get_importe(self):
      return self.natural+self.juridico
    importe = property(get_importe)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el modelo `jovenclub` y de paso formatearlo correctamente tu código? Creo que tengo la respuesta, pero necesito asegurarme de que te sirva y por eso pido ver el modelo.

Comment: @toledano ya esta los modelos en la pregunta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos a hacer un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para lo cual, vamos a usar este mini modelo, que tiene toda la información que necesitamos:

```
from django.db import models

class Ingresos(models.Model):
    club = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    natural = natural = models.FloatField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % self.club
```

> Observa como el código se colorea correctamente cuando usas correctamente el botón de formato: <kbd>{ }</kbd>.

Ahora vamos a usar unos datos de prueba:

```
id | club | natural
1  |   1  |   5.0
2  |   1  |   5.0
3  |   1  |   5.0
4  |   2  |   3.0
5  |   2  |   3.0
6  |   2  |   3.0
7  |   3  |   2.0
8  |   3  |   2.0
9  |   3  |   2.0
10 |   3  |   2.0
```

Hay tres registros del club `1`, todos con un valor en `natural` de `5`. hay 3 registros del club `2`, con un natural de 3 y hay 4 registros del club `3` con un valor asociado de natural igual a 2. Los totales serían 15 para el club 1, 9 para el club 2 y 8 para el club 3. El total general es 15 + 9 + 8 = 32. Eso es lo que queremos encontrar.

Vamos a usar el método `aggregate` para aplicar la función `Sum` a todos los registros.

```
In [3]: Ingresos.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('natural'))
Out[3]: {'natural__sum': 32.0}
```

El resultado es `32.0`, que es el resultado esperado.

Podemos mejorar un poco más nuestra consulta, asignando una etiqueta al resultado:

```
In [4]: Ingresos.objects.values('club').aggregate(total_general=Sum('natural'))
Out[4]: {'total_general': 32.0}
```

Ahora vamos a obtener los resultados agrupados por club. Para esto, usaremos el método **`Annotate`** que al contrario del anterior, agrupa los resultados **por objeto**. En nuestro ejemplo, queremos agrupar los resultados *por club*.

Simplemente vamos a agregar el campo indicado para que haga el resumen, de la siguiente manera:

```
In [5]: Ingresos.objects.values('club').annotate(Sum('natural'))
Out[5]: <QuerySet [{'club': 1, 'natural__sum': 15.0}, {'club': 2, 'natural__sum': 9.0}, {'club': 3, 'natural__sum': 8.0}]>
```

Como puedes observar este es el resultado esperado. Y de la misma manera, podemos agregar una etiqueta para mejorar la presentación y el control.

```
In [6]: Ingresos.objects.values('club').annotate(natural_por_club=Sum('natural'))
Out[6]: <QuerySet [{'club': 1, 'natural_por_club': 15.0}, {'club': 2, 'natural_por_club': 9.0}, {'club': 3, 'natural_por_club': 8.0}]>
```

> #### Importante
>
> La agrupación que haces usando el método `values` es diferente dependiendo del lugar donde hagas el resumen y dónde agrupes los datos. En el ejemplo anterior, primero los agrupas y luego los resumes, pero observa el siguiente ejemplo:
>
> ```
>  In [7]: Ingresos.objects.annotate(natural_por_club=Sum('natural')).values('club')
>  Out[7]: <QuerySet [{'club': 1}, {'club': 1}, {'club': 1}, {'club': 2}, {'club': 2}, {'club': 2}, {'club': 3}, {'club': 3}, {'club': 3}, {'club': 3}]>
> ```

Para concluir, puedes agregar al método `Annotate` las operaciones que necesites, separadas por coma y cada una de ellas puede tener su propia etiqueta. Y más aún, puedes traer campos relacionados y agruparlos, por lo que una consulta como la siguiente es perfectamente válida.

```
jovenclub.objects.values('club').annotate(\
    total_plan_gra=Sum('plan_gral'),\
    total_juridico=Sum('juridico'),\
    total_natural=Sum('natural')
)
```

De modo que es posible que en una sola sentencia tengas todas tus operaciones de agregación.

---

> #### Nota
>
> Es importante señalar que al contrario de **Aggregate**, el método **Annotate** devuelve un *QuerySet*, esto quiere decir que no es una función final y puedes seguir aplicando filtros y consultas, como lo haces normalmente con cualquier QuerySet.

Comment: ¡Buenísima respuesta!

Comment: Destacable que en la respuesta misma explícitamente se promueve [mcve].